# How to get with RectangleChart the same x-axis labelling as with GeneralizedBarChart?

Tags: plotting, histograms, charts

I am still using **GeneralizedBarChart**,although Mathematica documentation says:

> As of Version 7.0, GeneralizedBarChart has been superseded by RectangleChart.

However, I could so far not figure out, how to conveniently get the same output, especially of the x-axis labelling, from **RectangleChart** or from any other Mathematica function.

**GeneralizedBarChart** is used by giving for each bar the position, height, and widths:

> GeneralizedBarChart[{ {*pos1,height1,widths1*} ..} ]

For example:

```
Needs["BarCharts`"]

data={{-0.125, 1225, 0.15}, {0.025, 2007, 0.15}, {0.175, 1017, 
  0.15}, {0.325, 1508, 0.15}, {0.475, 2878, 0.15}, {0.625, 2785, 
  0.15}, {0.775, 2042, 0.15}, {0.925, 4257, 0.15}, {1.075, 651, 0.15}};

GeneralizedBarChart[data, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

My question is: How do I get a similar output with a labeled x-axis using **RectangleChart**, **BarChart** or any other Mathematica function? 
The output of Mathematica's **Histogram** function would be also ok. But as far as I see **Histogram** needs as input the raw data and does not accept already binned data.

Thank you for your help.

Daniel

Answer (score 5):

You can use `RectangleChart` with a custom `ChartElementFunction` that modifies the built-in chart element functions to re-center the rectangles based on the first column of input data.

```
ClearAll[cF]
cF[f_: "Rectangle", o : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{ori = Charting`ChartStyleInformation["BarOrigin"], box}, 
   box = Switch[ori, Top | Bottom, {#3[[1]] + {-1, 1}/2 Subtract @@ #[[1]], #[[2]]}, 
     Right | Left, {#[[1]], #3[[1]] + {-1, 1}/2 Subtract @@ #[[2]]}]; 
   ChartElementDataFunction[f, o][box, ##2]] &
```

You also need a function to transform your 3D data to a form that can be used with `RectangleChart`:

```
ClearAll[gbcToRc]
gbcToRc = Thread[#[[All, {3, 2}]] -> #[[All, 1]]] &;
```

or

```
gbcToRc  = {#3, #2} -> # & @@@#& (* thanks: Mr.Wizard *)
```

**Examples:**

```
data = {{-0.125, 1225, 0.15}, {0.025, 2007, 0.15}, {0.175, 1017,  0.15}, 
        {0.325, 1508, 0.15}, {0.475, 2878, 0.15}, {0.625, 2785,  0.15}, 
        {0.775, 2042, 0.15}, {0.925, 4257, 0.15}, {1.075, 651, 0.15}};

RectangleChart[gbcToRc @ data, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, BarSpacing -> 0, ChartStyle -> 3, 
 ChartElementFunction -> cF[]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
RectangleChart[gbcToRc @ data, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, BarSpacing -> 0, ChartStyle -> 3, 
 ChartElementFunction -> cF["FadingRectangle", "GradientOrigin" -> Top]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
RectangleChart[gbcToRc @ data, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, BarSpacing -> 0, ChartStyle -> 3, BarOrigin -> Top, 
 ChartElementFunction -> cF["FadingRectangle", "GradientOrigin" -> Top]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
RectangleChart[gbcToRc @ data, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, BarSpacing -> 0, ChartStyle -> 3, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartElementFunction -> cF["FadingRectangle", "GradientOrigin" -> Top]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
RectangleChart[gbcToRc @ data, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, BarSpacing -> 0, ChartStyle -> 3, BarOrigin -> Right, 
 ChartElementFunction -> cF["FadingRectangle", "GradientOrigin" -> Top]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is a nice answer, which clearly shows that one has to do a lot of gymnastics to  achieve with `RectangleChart` the same result as with `GeneralizedBarChart`. Thanks.

Comment: Great answer!  `{#3, #2} -> # & @@@ data` also works, and though it may be a little less efficient that shouldn't matter here, especially since plotting functions have become rather slow.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard. I updated with the alternative you suggested.

Comment: Can one in this aproach also show two overlapping histograms with two monochrom bar colors? Similar to my answer below using `Histogram`?  `RectangleChart[gbcToRc /@ {data, data2},ChartStyle -> {Red, Green},...]`does not work.

Comment: @dnet, i will look into how to modify `cF` to handle multiple data sets.

Answer (score 3):

It's relatively easy to put together a function to generate your own primitives from the `data` formatted as you already have it:

```
Clear[bchart]
bchart[data_, filling_: Blue, border_: Black] := Graphics[{
   EdgeForm[border], FaceForm[filling],
   Rectangle[{#1 - #3/2, 0}, {#1 + #3/2, #2}] & @@@ data},
  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
]

bchart[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The colors default to blue filling with black borders, but you can indicate your own:

```
bchart[data, Darker@Green, Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, with this approach one cannot use the many options that `Histogram` or `RectangleChart` offer out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I found now the following solution combining Histogram and WeightedData, which is good enough for the problem at hand, where all histogram bars are of identical width, not overlapping and without gaps.

```
plothisto[dat : {{_, _, _} ..}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := plothisto[{dat}, opts];

plothisto[dat : {{{_, _, _}..} ..}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{xmin, xmax, dx},
  dx = dat[[1, 1, 3]];
  xmin = dat[[1, 1, 1]] - dx/2;
  xmax = dat[[1, -1, 1]] + dx/2;
  Histogram[
   MapThread[
    WeightedData, {dat[[All, All, 1]], dat[[All, All, 2]]}], {xmin, 
    xmax, dx}, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Histogram]]]
  ]
```

For example:

```
data = {{-0.125, 1225, 0.15}, {0.025, 2007, 0.15}, {0.175, 1017, 
    0.15}, {0.325, 1508, 0.15}, {0.475, 2878, 0.15}, {0.625, 2785, 
    0.15}, {0.775, 2042, 0.15}, {0.925, 4257, 0.15}, {1.075, 651, 
    0.15}};
data2 = data;
data2[[All, 2]] = RandomReal[{0, 2000}, Length[data]];
plothisto[{data, data2}, ChartStyle -> Opacity[1], Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False]
```

[image]

The advantage for me is that the graphical output of Histogram is close to my needs.

However, this is surely not a general replacement of GeneralizedBarChart!